# What does "the darkest of nights" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Over at [German.SE](http://german.stackexchange.com) we have a [question involving "the darkest of nights"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-do-i-say-something-is-the-superlative-of-a-group-in-german). I would like to know what this expression actually means, but I didn't find it in an online dictionary (e.g. [leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?search=darkest+of+nights), [dict.cc](http://dict.leo.org/ende?search=darkest+of+nights), [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/british/?q=darkest+of+nights)).

So what does this expression mean? Is it a figure of speech? I can imagine at least two meanings: It's the time of a particular night when it is darkest, or it's the darkest of a (not specified) number of nights.

Comment: What don't you understand from the dictionary definitions of those words?

Comment: @Matt: I'm fluent enough in English to understand every single word - but that doesn't yet make the phrase clear to me. I'll expand the question to make it clearer.

Comment: +1 The expansion is better than the question. A fine distinction, indeed.

Comment: @MattЭллен and the upvoter, I would have agreed, if I hadn't read mfg's answer below. It was blissful ignorance so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

German.SE was discussing [superlatives](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=superlative) (in the sense of grammar).

In that context, "the darkest of nights" simply means "a night darker than any other (of an unspecified number)."

You can use it in a literal sense, as in "it was the darkest of nights when the power grid failed and the moon was new."

Or, you can use it a figurative sense to convey that it was a night of great sorrow or some other sense of the word *[dark](http://www.wordnik.com/words/dark)*.

Comment: OK, I understand the literal meaning of the superlative. What isn't clear to me is how and when the expression is used. Does your last sentence in plain language mean that it's a worn out figure of speech?

Comment: I think it's an expression that's become so overused that it's almost become a cliche, likely to induce eye-rolling as the examples in that fiction contest.

Comment: This. The OP is looking for how the superlative is used *in this case*. +1.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt, as to how and when the metaphorical expression is used, one might say that "When the Berlin Wall went up was one of the darkest of nights for Germany"

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: It hasn't achieved the legendary status of [It was a dark and stormy night](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_was_a_dark_and_stormy_night), but it's quite likely to be seen as a bit "tired" by many. Personally I really laugh at Terry Pratchett's usages - one of many being *It wasn't a dark and stormy night. It should have been, but there's the weather for you.* (Good Omens, Neil Gaiman & Terry Pratchett, 1991)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hendrik was responding to my original answer that _the darkest of nights_ sounded like it came from an entry in the [Bulwer-Lytton Fiction Contest](http://www.bulwer-lytton.com/2011.htm).

Comment: Spooky! Until I just followed your link, I actually thought the original *dark and stormy night* was from Snoopy in Peanuts! I wonder what Bulwer-Lytton would think if he could know how his deathless prose lives on!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Snoopy?! Excellent!

Comment: @Gnawme: May I add another question? In the literal sense, why wouldn't I just say "the darkest night"? What kind of construction is this "of nights"? (OK, sorry, this was 3 questions `:-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik: I think "darkest of nights" rather than "darkest night" is just an effort at being poetic. It doesn't really change the meaning. A very short phrase tends to be less emphatic. A very long phrase also tends to lose emphasis. There's some length in the middle with peak emphasis. Like, "Bob is a tall man." Too fast: not very emphatic. "Bob is the tallest of men." More emphatic. "Bob is a man who is taller than most other men." Too drawn out: losing emphasis.

Comment: @Jay: Thanks a lot, this "effort at being poetic" confirms a vague feeling I had.

Comment: @HendrikVogt You can use this form to emphasize that it is the darkest of dark nights, just as you can say "the holiest of days" to emphasize that the day is the most holy of holy days.

Comment: @Gnawme: Like the King James Bible says the Jewish temple had a "Holy of Holies". That sounds very superlative and awe-inspiring to me. The New International Version translates the same phrase as "Most Holy Place", which just doesn't have the same ring.

Comment: @Jay Yes, most modern Bible translations seem to have had tin-eared translators. (But not all -- see Robert Alter's or Willis Barnstone's efforts.)

Answer (score 7):

The *darkest of nights* could be a metaphorical expression to mean the very worst of bad times. Of course it could be interpreted literally to mean the darkest night among many nights.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this expression in literary texts. It means a very dark night, with no moonlight at all and it is used to enhance a feeling of foreboding. It can be called [a hyperbole](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyperbole).

Answer (score 4):

It might be better to use both halves in answeering your question. The first half, "Dark Night" refers to period of personal upheaval or crisis. Both halves: Dark Night, Early Dawn (DNED) is a phrase whose usage probably best elucidates the fuller context behind what a Dark Night exactly is. [Transpersonal Studies](http://www.transpersonalstudies.org/) usage can be summed up in the following;

> "Dark Night...", as in Dark Night, Early Dawn typically can be used to refer to a period of great spiritual testing and, when coupled with "...Early Dawn", transformation. For more you might gloss over the book [Summary of central metaphor in *Dark Night, Early Dawn*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0791446069)

Frequently a Dark Night is a period in which the mettle of a given subject is tested to such an extent as to not only unwind the topical or superficial egoic structures of the person, but when harnessed the crisis energy can additionally be utilized to unwind and deconstruct the foundational and subterranean structures.

Also, the actual crisis or context may not objectively warrant such a description, but the diligence and energy channelled into the situation and egoic structures involved would be sufficient to be a Dark Night experience to the subject.

When used in the superlative, there is an understanding of the Darkest Night laying bare the subject's entire self as a collection of dis-integrated parts. There is, in the sense of the Early Dawn, an opportunity to collect these fragmented elements of the person and to integrate them into a more cohesive personhood.

Comment: I suppose you may not have anticipated a new-age-y answer, but I thought some flavor text might add to your understanding.

Comment: +1 If there was ever a *useful* answer, this is it.

Comment: I'm still a bit overtaxed by your answer, but thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 2):

Literally, the phrase means a night that is darker than most nights, for example because it is a new moon, or clouds obscure the moon and stars. On such a night it may be difficult to see any danger until it is too late -- danger ranging from something on the ground that you trip over to wild animals or violent people attacking you. Thus such a night is considered scary. Thus figuratively the phrase can refer to a frightening time, like "When the dictator took over our country was plunged into the darkest of nights."

Answer (score 2):

The context or setting under which it is used is more likely to reveal its particular intention, which is to say that both your's and Irene's perceptions are all correct.

I *could*, however, argue that its nuances and the ensuing ambiguities are what makes it more beautiful than a precise substitute. It is for you to decide whether its poetic undertone and its literal insensibility are contextually more significant than any fixed meaning someone else may offer.

Comment: The OP suggests two possible meanings, which are not equally correct. It would be very unlikely to mean "the time of a particular night when it is darkest" - we would have to say something like *the darkest time of the night* to get this across. Rather, "it's the darkest of a (not specified) number of nights" - the superlative meaning - is correct. It's true that it is commonly used as hyperbole, as Irene and others mention, to just mean it's a very dark night; why do you think that gives the phrase a "literal insensibility"?

Comment: Its construction requests a personal viewpoint from the reader on what the darkest night might be. If the phrase were to describe a night precisely as per the author's intentions, the author would have chosen a different and more elaborate phrase. When one _reads_ a phrase like "the greatest of..." or "the darkest of...," one immediately positions an image in one's mind of the object following "of." Using an ambiguous (uncertain, indifferent, insensible) phrase is a request for such a comparison or thought by the reader, more than a call for a precise description of the author's perception.

Comment: Thus, if you write "the darkest of nights," your objective must be to instill one or more thoughts or a pondering rather than any isolated author-specific perception of the particular night. It gives a poetic 'jolt', but does not set the scene too precisely. It allows the possibility that what the author leaves uncertain about the night is perhaps forthcoming. To me, the author's decision is one between precision and imprecision, which depend on the context and the author's objectives.

Comment: Down voters better not be overenthusiastic and quick on the draw.

Comment: I still have some difficulty understanding your answer, but your comments were very helpful indeed.